# Running Custom Media Reciever for Chromecast Times out after 5 minutes Using .Net Maui

Tags: android, maui

I currently have Chromecast running from a .Net Maui App.  I've built a custom reciever, When I have it connecting to and communicating with the Reciever from the Sender in my local program.  However the Reciever times out after 5 minutes.   Is there a way to send a heart beat check to the reciever to keep it alive.  I cant tell if the session is Timing out.   My Guess is the Media Player on the HTML page.  I do still have the
`cast-media-player></cast-media-player>` on the  on my page. I hide it immedieatly after the page loads.  Ive tried it without it on the page and with. exact same affect.

I tried to modify the Options on the Reciever  but it doesn't seem to have any affect.

Here is the top of the receiver :

```
const options = new cast.framework.CastReceiverOptions();

options.maxInactivity = 3600;
options.disableidleTimeout = true;

context.start(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to load non-existent image from the sender to the receiver every 4 minutes:

```
CastSession session = mSessionManager.CurrentCastSession;
if (null != session) {
    MediaInfo.Builder builder = new MediaInfo.Builder("https://some-inaudible-clip.png")
                .SetStreamType(StreamType.Buffered)
                .SetContentType("image/png")
                .SetMetadata(new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadataType.Photo));
    session.RemoteMediaClient.Load(builder.Build(), true);
}
```

2. You can also try to simply re-declare setTimeout as a dummy no-op function before loading the Chromecast receiver script. For more information, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49291264/17455524).